# Ubuntu 18.04 Trackpad Issues when scrolling

Tags: 18.04, touchpad, scrolling

There is this weird issue when scrolling fast on a long page and suddenly the touchpad stops scrolling and the cursor move instead, then trying to scroll again works fine, but it's always happening, and it's really annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, you just need to replace the trackpad driver, this answer shows how https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/7562/15434

Answer (score 0):

My HP 2000 does the same exact thing. I don't believe it is a software or hardware problem, I think it is just the way things are. I've tried moving my fingers a little more carefully and it helps some. It's just the way things are with touchpads I guess. Maybe we should invest in a mouse...

Comment: Yeah, if you press instead of touch it works perfectly fine, but it works flawlessly in Windows 10, that's why this is bothering me.

Comment: It's odd that *anything* works in Windows (especially 10) but the touchpad working fine there is odd. I've never used Windows with a laptop and used touchpad so I wouldn't know. Like I said that is really odd. The only thing I can think of is maybe the default setting for Windows or different then Ubuntu's.